# Stop listening single specific listener, socket.off is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

I connect my socket and start listening after emit,

```
  socket.emit('groupChat', {
      "groups": {
        "group_id": "${widget.groupId}",
        "type": "GET_GROUP_MESSAGES",
      }
    });

  socket.on('message', (data) {
      'message updating: $data'.log();
    });
```

Now its start listening every message from backend is working fine but I want to stop listening `socket.on('message')` so I tried `socket.off('message')` but after that its still receiving messages. Does anyone know how to stop specific single listener in flutter.

I am using null safety version of [socket_io_client 2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client/versions/2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0) its not have function of `socket.removeListener('message')` Check this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping a reference to your handler, then pass that handler to the `off` function, like so:

```dart
final EventHandler messageHandler = (data) {
  print('message updating: $data');
};

socket.on('message', messageHandler);

// Later
socket.off('message', messageHandler);
```